# Not able to pull last row data from google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seswn.jpg)
[Sending Middle Data not last row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyLnn.jpg)

Hello, can someone please help me? I just can't get code to pull the last data entry from gSheets. I am entering a google form, then the data gets converted to a PDF and is Email'ed as an attachment. when I run the script it works but it will pull data from middle row or row with no data. can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function pdfMaker() {
  const id = 'ID123456789';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PDF-Data');
  const numRows = sheet.getLastColumn();
  const lastRowData = sheet.getRange(numRows, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  const emailTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('qaemail.html');
  const name = lastRowData[0];
  const pom = lastRowData[4];
  const email = lastRowData[3];;
  
  if (!email || !/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email)) {
    Logger.log("Invalid email: " + email);
    return;
  }
  
  const user = {
    AgentName: name,
    DateOfEvaluation: lastRowData[2]
  };

  emailTemplate.user = user;
  emailTemplate.id = pom;

  let html = `<div><img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/123456789/view?usp=sharing" style="width: 200px;"></div>`;
      html += '<hr>';
      html += '<h4>Quality Evaluation</h4>';
      html += '<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">';
      html += '<tbody>';
      html += `<tr><td>Quality Evaluation for:</td><td>${lastRowData[0]}</td></tr>`;
      html += `<tr><td>Date of Evaluation:</td><td>${lastRowData[1]}</td></tr>`;
      html += `<tr><td>Evaluation made by:</td><td>${lastRowData[2]}</td></tr>`;
      html += `<tr><td>POM Number:</td><td>${lastRowData[4]}</td></tr>`;
      html += `<tr><td>Call Type:</td><td>${lastRowData[5]}</td></tr>`;
      html += `<tr><td>Evaluation Score:</td><td>${lastRowData[6]}</td></tr>`;
      html += '</tbody></table>';
      html += '<hr>';
      
      
  const htmlBody = emailTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, MimeType.HTML);
  blob.setName(lastRowData[0] + ' ' + lastRowData[4] + '.pdf');
  const subject = 'Quality Evaluation for' + ' ' + lastRowData[0] + ' ' + 'POM' + ' ' + lastRowData[4];

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
    attachments: [blob.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
  });
  sheet.getRange(numRows, 26).setValue("Email Sent");
 
}
```

What I try to do is enter a form using google forms and as soon as form is submitted, that PDF is created and sent by email. is  doing it but not last row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const lastRowData = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
```